# ALERTS FRONTPAGE

Tags: joomla-4.x, error-warning

I have alerts in frontpage that I have not been able to fix for months
[image: ALERTA]
https://redes.editorasalvaje.net/internet
https://redes.editorasalvaje.net/rural
https://redes.editorasalvaje.net/recursos-herramientas
ETC.

Answer (score 0):

Disable JCHOptimize and Joomla cache, then disable your third party extensions (plugins and components) one by one to see which one shows the alert.

Answer (score 0):

These look like warnings rather than errors - Click System in the admin menu and check Global Configration > Server > Error Reporting. Set this to None. If the site is working as expected with these 'errors' displaying then setting error reporting to 'None' should in theory, hide them. I visited the URLs you provided but could not see the 'errors' in your screenshot.